# How do I calculate a ratio between rows based on criteria in the data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario in which I need to determine the ratio of a value in one row with the total of all values in a several rows. This is simple enough using window functions, I take the value and divide by the `SUM(Value) OVER(...)` the relevant rows. What complicates this is that I want the relevant rows to be dictated not by a row count but instead using the value in another column compared to the aggregate of the value in question.

Specifically, if the **Back** value is 20, I would like to get the ratio between *C1* and *C2* going back enough **Week**s such that the `SUM(Value)` for those **Week**s is greater than 20, but the fewest number of weeks that it takes to surpass 20..

Here is an example of my scenario:

[image: example data]

The **Ratio** column is the ratio between

```
SUM(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY Comp ORDER BY Week ROWS ... )
```

and **Back**. The part that I cannot solve is the `...` where the window criteria is set. I have attempted this using CTE, but that didn't get me any further than simply using analytic functions.

Example data:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (Week INT, Comp VARCHAR(8), Value INT, Back INT);

INSERT INTO @data VALUES (1,'C1',2,10);
INSERT INTO @data VALUES (1,'C2',8,10);
INSERT INTO @data VALUES (2,'C1',4,20);
INSERT INTO @data VALUES (2,'C2',6,20);
INSERT INTO @data VALUES (3,'C1',3,18);
INSERT INTO @data VALUES (3,'C2',7,18);
INSERT INTO @data VALUES (4,'C1',5,8);
INSERT INTO @data VALUES (4,'C2',5,8);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, as I can't test as the sample data can't be consumed, but perhaps this?

```sql
CASE Back WHEN 10 THEN Value / (Back * 1.)
          WHEN 20 THEN SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Week ORDER BY Comp
                                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) / (Back * 1.)
END AS Ratio
```

Comment: 10 and 20 are examples, the data could have any value greater than 0. How would you like the data to be presented?

Comment: DDL and DML statements are by far the best way, @DaveRoss . If you also have other requirements that should be reflected in your sample data.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, I adjusted the example data to demonstrate that it could be more varied, and added a temp table definition with the sample data.